# Longest cycle of key-value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, python-3.5

I've got a question regarding Python 3 which I can't wrap my head around. 
Let's say I got the following dictionary.

```
{'Noah': 'Liam', 'Ethan': 'Peter', 'Liam': 'Olivia', 'Emma': 'Ethan', 'Peter': 'Emma', 'Olivia': 'Noah'}
```

I need to find the longest cycle of key-value pairs in this dictionary.

In pseudo-code this would be

```
for key in dictionary:
    find value in dictionary, make this key
    continue process untill start key has been detected
```

In this example the longest cycle would be:

Noah --> Liam --> Olivia --> Noah (length of 3)

I have no clue how to go about this, even though I know exactly what I want to do. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword to your problem is recursion... Or google "linked lists".  Draw what you want to do on a sheet of paper and think of each step individually.. with that small amount of data it is possible.

It's for sure not the prettiest solution but it works. And you get the point.

```
import copy

people = {'Noah': 'Liam', 'Ethan': 'Peter', 'Liam': 'Olivia', 'Emma': 'Ethan',   'Peter': 'Emma', 'Olivia': 'Noah'}


def walk_the_links(person, subtree, counter):
    print(person)
    if person in subtree:
        counter += 1
        next_person = subtree[person]
        subtree.pop(person)
        counter = walk_the_links(next_person, subtree, counter)
    return counter

for person in people:
    subtree = copy.deepcopy(people) 
    counter = 0
    length_tree = walk_the_links(person, subtree, counter)
    print(length_tree)
```

Comment: Believe me... I have tried. I can post you the code I came up with in 100 different ways but that will just show you how little I knew on how to tackle this issue. Oh, and it isn't homework.

Comment: No worries, i did not wan't to offend you. I hope it helped... Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ i think its a great resource to learn.